# what is the difference between these two function pointer declarations?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int *(*const fun[])(int argc, char **argv)
```

and

```
const int *(* fun[])(int argc, char **argv).
```

Is the first one the array of const function pointers returning integer pointer ?

Comment: When you asked `cdecl`, what did it tell you?

Comment: [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) gives 'syntax error' for both of them. Yet GCC doesn't complain...

Comment: For cdecl to parse it you need to remove the parameter names, i.e. make it "int *(*const fun[])(int , char **)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is an array of read-only pointers (i.e. you can't change `fun[i]`) to a function receiving an `int` and a `char **`, and returning a pointer to `int`.

The second is pretty similar, except that you can change `fun[i]`, but the function it points to returns a pointer to a read-only integer.

So, in short:

```
/* First declaration 
int *(*const fun[])(int argc, char **argv)
*/
int arg1;
char **arg2;
int *example = (*fun[i])(arg1, arg2);
*example = 14; /* OK */
example = &arg1; /* OK */
fun[i] = anoter_function; /* INVALID - fun[] is an array of read-only pointers */

/* Second declaration 
const int *(* fun[])(int argc, char **argv)
*/
const int *example2 = (*fun[i])(arg1, arg2);
fun[i] = another_function; /* OK */
*example2 = 14; /* INVALID - fun[i] returns pointer to read-only value. */
example2 = &arg1; /* OK */
```

Comment: should `example2` be `const`?